# Vertica - WITH clause is not recognized in actual query

Tags: sql, vertica

Please take a look at the following Vertica SQLcode:

```
   WITH date_range AS
    (SELECT YEAR(now() - interval '1' MONTH) ||MONTH(now() - interval '1' MONTH) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now() - interval '1' MONTH, 'mm')) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now(), 'mm') - interval '1' DAY)                              AS month1
              , YEAR(now() - interval '2' MONTH) ||MONTH(now() - interval '2' MONTH) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now() - interval '2' MONTH, 'mm')) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now() - interval '1' MONTH, 'mm') - interval '1' DAY) AS month2
    )
 SELECT regexp_substr(
    (SELECT month1
           FROM date_range), '[^#]*', 1, 1)
```

I have a 420 rows-long query, and I need to use "month1" and "month2" as variables many time in my code. Unfortunately, Vertica still doesn't support variables, so I tried to use a WITH clause instead.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work, as I keep getting the following error message:

```
(4566) ERROR: Relation "date_range" does not exist
```

So help me God (or Stack Overflow)

Comment: P.S. for easy maintenance of the code, please don't tell me to remove the "WITH" and just use the whole `SELECT YEAR(now() - interval '1' MONTH) ||MONTH(now() - interval '1' MONTH) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now() - interval '1' MONTH, 'mm')) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now(), 'mm') - interval '1' DAY)` statement. It repeats at least 10 times in my code (Is it efficient? Yes it is. It's a part of an automatically generated alert.  Why don't you use join? Because it is all over the code, in many nested queries etc.  Many Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you want:

```
WITH date_range AS (
      SELECT YEAR(now() - interval '1' MONTH) ||MONTH(now() - interval '1' MONTH) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now() - interval '1' MONTH, 'mm')) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now(), 'mm') - interval '1' DAY)                              AS month1,
             YEAR(now() - interval '2' MONTH) ||MONTH(now() - interval '2' MONTH) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now() - interval '2' MONTH, 'mm')) ||'#'||DATE(TRUNC(now() - interval '1' MONTH, 'mm') - interval '1' DAY) AS month2
    )
SELECT regexp_substr(month1, '[^#]*', 1, 1)
FROM date_range;
```

In an actual query, you would do this as:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(dr.month1, '[^#]*', 1, 1)
FROM date_range dr CROSS JOIN
     . . .;
```

I often call such CTEs `params` to highlight that they are providing parameters to the query.